# putting an input inside a loop err resulting

Tags: python

Why does this code result in an error? Does the loop jump the input or does it not store it in memory?

```
contacts = [
    ('James', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]


#user_input = input()

for contact in contacts:
    if  input() == contact[0]:
        print("it works bro")
```

I want to be able to declare an input and store it while im inside a loop as shown above.

Comment: The logic might not be what you intended, but I don't see how this code could throw an exception. Please add the full traceback of the error to your question. But where do you expect the return value of `input` to be saved? You don't assign it to any variable.

Comment: The code works fine. It does help to identify the prompt in the `input` statement, for example: `input('Fill in contact')`

Comment: Matthias im on sololearn playground

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usercode/file0.py", line 13, in <module>
    if input() == contact[0]:
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Also the comparison is case sensitive so typing 'amanda' for example wouldnt give the correct output. you can use
`for contact in contacts:
    if user_input.lower() == contact[0].lower():
        print("it works bro")`

Comment: @ThamsanqaSithole I don't know what _sololearn playground_ is, but it looks as if this platform does automatic tests of your code. Wild guess: It seems as if you should only use one `input` before the loop starts. Then in the loop you have to compare the inputted value with `contact[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Sololearn Playground, which has a bit different input methods. 

**EOFError: EOF when reading a line** indicates that the program encountered an End-of-File (EOF) condition while trying to read a line of input from the user. This means that the user has entered an empty line or has closed the input stream.
Error appears only when you enter less than 5 strings (you request input 5 times).


The code is correct and everything works fine. But, if you want to fix this error you can handle exception like this:

```py
contacts = [
    ('James', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]

try:
    for contact in contacts:
        if input() == contact[0]:
            print("it works bro")
except EOFError:
    pass
```